# Render html content stay on current page with form action set to different url in Django

Tags: javascript, python, django, forms

My question is there is a way to render html content(bootstrap alert) on the current page(1st page) with POST action set to a different url(2nd page)?

I have following content in views.py:

```
def calendar(req): # 1st page
    return render(req,'calendar.html')

def result(req): # 2nd page
    if req.method == 'POST':
        xxx
        else:
            no_data = "xxx"
            context = { 'no_data': no_data }
            return render(req, 'calendar.html', context)
        xxx
        return render(req,'result.html',context)
```

The form info is submitted to different url(2nd page) in calendar.html:

```
{% if no_data %}  
    <div class="alert alert-warning" role="alert">
        {{ no_data }}
    </div> 

<form action="{% url 'result' %}" method="POST">
```

Thank you.

Comment: Does the 1st page have to change its contents after the POST request? If yes, do you want the page to refresh after the request or change contents without refresh?

Comment: 1st page does not change contents, just show the alert. cuz 1st page is just to let user filter conditions. Please let me know if you don't understand me. thank you.

Comment: cuz now if I want to show error message, the url would be http://127.0.0.1:8000/result/, but actually the content is the 1st page, which is right, just url should also be the 1st page:  http://127.0.0.1:8000/, that not contains /result/ at the end.